# Issue with two text box input focus with jquery and jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that contains a popup div that contains form that contains this snippet of code:

```
<input type="radio" name="periodtype" value="preset" checked> 
Period
    <select name="presetval">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">30 Days</option>
        <option value="2">60 Days</option>
    </select>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="periodtype" value="manual"> 
Periode
    <input type="text" name="periodstart" class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" name="periodend" class="datepicker">
```

When I click on the dropdown select, the select will only show the dropdown box if I keep holding my mouse button. Once I let it go, the dropdown immediately closed.

When I click on the second input box, the focus immediately changed into first input box.

Yes, I'm currently trying to develop two text input that can display dropdown date picker from jquery UI. I'm aware that there's a circulating discussion on the internet about this weirdness with date picker of jquery UI. But I still haven't attached the date event trigger yet. And it doesn't seem to matter whether I load the jquery UI plugins or not. *This weirdness only stop if I don't load jquery at all*.

You can see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chenliyong/h1qg0bat/) here for illustration. The problem is, the issue can't be reproduced on the jsfiddle. I've even tried to reproduce using the whole popup form, but still can't reproduce it.

How can I fix this issue? Is this really a jquery UI problem?

Comment: did you include the script of date picker in your fiddle?the sample in fiddle does not have date picker on them

Comment: You said "When I click on the dropdown select, the select will only show the dropdown box if I keep holding my mouse button." - It doesn't do this for me

Comment: Can u add jQuery code here?

Comment: This actually still does not have datepicker implemented yet. That was the point. The datepicker still hasn't been implemented yet, but I already can see the issue arise with text box and input control focus, which is (according to what people on the internet said) usually arise when the datepicker has been implemented. And, yeah, I can't reproduced it either on the jsfiddle. There's no jquery code related to this issue, aside for the include for jquery and jquery ui itself.